# List has no rows for assignment to SObject . if i am passing hard code id its working fine

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="documentForEmail" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form >

 <br></br>
 <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!EventDoclist}" var="Eventfile" styleClass="homeTab" id="Attachment_List">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:dataTable value="{!Eventfile.Supdocname}" var="Supdocfile"  id="Attachment_List" rules="none">
                    <apex:column value=" {!Supdocfile}"/>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class documentForEmail{

  public Id appId {get;set;}


       public vlocity_ins__Application__c app 
    {
        get
        {
            if(app==null)
                app = [SELECT id,  Opportunity__r.Qualifying_Event_Reason__c,Opportunity__r.Qualifying_Event_Type__c FROM vlocity_ins__Application__c  where   id =:appid];
            return app;
        }
        set;
    }  

    public String QualifyingEventReason 
    {
        get {return app.Opportunity__r.Qualifying_Event_Reason__c;}
    }



    public EventDocumentlist EventDoclist 

    {

        get 
        {
            EventDocumentlist eventDocs = new EventDocumentlist();
            eventDocs.Eventname = QualifyingEventReason;
            eventDocs.Supdocname = new list<string>();

           // for (Supporting_Document_List__c SDL : Supporting_Document_List__c.getall().values())
            for (Supporting_Document_List__c SDL : [Select id,Event_Type__c,Document_Desc__c,Order_by__c from Supporting_Document_List__c Order by Order_by__c ASC])

            {
                if(SDL.Event_Type__c!=null && QualifyingEventReason!=null){
                  if(SDL.Event_Type__c.toLowerCase() == QualifyingEventReason.toLowerCase())

                    eventDocs.Supdocname.add(SDL.Document_Desc__c) ;
                }  

            }



        return eventDocs; 
    }
    }


     Public class EventDocumentlist{
        Public string Eventname {get;set;}
        Public list<string> Supdocname {get;set;}

         }
      Public class SupportingDoc {

        Public Supporting_Document__c SupDoc {get;set;}



    }}
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code so the community can read it.

Comment: I fixed the formatting in your post. Please do not post comments to include code. Next time, please use the `{}` tool. Your edit actually removed my fix, and Derek rolled it back.

Comment: For the future: Stackexchange will generally _not_ display anything that looks like html unless it is formatted as inline code, or as a code block. This is a security measure (otherwise, people would inject all manner of malicious html/javascript into questions and answers). There are a few "safe" html tags that can be used, but that's not going to include any visualforce tags. Highlight the code/markup you want to format, then press the `{}` button that David mentioned. (highlighting code, then pressing `ctrl` + `k` does the same thing. Using 3 backtickcs is another way to mark a code block).

Answer (score 2):

The cause is pretty straightforward: you never populate `appid`, so it's `null`, and no record has a `null` Id value.

You will need to either build your controller as an [extension of the standard controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm), which will allow you to obtain the Id of the current record from the standard controller, or accept a URL parameter to identify the current record, e.g., `/apex/MyPage?id=001000000000000`.

The former is most likely to be the correct approach. If you store the standard controller in an instance variable called `controller`, you can then get the current record's Id via `controller.getRecord().Id`.

Note that you'd also change your `<apex:page>` markup to declare `standardController="vlocity_ins__Application__c" extensions="documentForEmail"`, and write a constructor in your controller class accepting an `ApexPages.StandardController` instance:

```
public documentForEmail(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}
```

See the linked documentation above for more details.

Comment: i have update code but still getting same error.

Comment: @alpha If you're getting the same error, then you have the same root problem. You need to trace how data is being injected into your query and ensure you have a non-null Id at each step.

Comment: Thanks @david for your help .